# Visual Studio 2010 project file filters

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I have a complex C/C++ bunch of applications that I'm working on which is supposed to also be platform independent. So far, is UNIX/Windows compatible and it runs fine. However, maintaing this monster on VS2010 is a nightmare. I have the following file structure:

```
/
  sources
    lib1
      include
        ...
      src
        ...
    lib2
      include
        ...
      src
        ...
    app3
      include
        ...
      src
        ...
  builders
    cmake
      ...
    make
      ...
    VS2010
      vs2010.sln
      lib1
        lib1.vcxproj
        lib1.vcxproj.filters
      lib2
        lib2.vcxproj
        lib2.vcxproj.filters
      app3
        app3.vcxproj
        app3.vcxproj.filters
```

As we can see, because everything is platform independent, I had to completely separate the builders from sources. IMHO, that itself is a very good practice and it should be enforced by everyone :)

Here is the problem now... VS2010 is completely unusable when it comes to organize the include/sources files in filters. You have to do that manually by repeatedly doing "Add -> New Filter" followed by "Add -> Exiting Item". I have a **VERY** complex folder structure and files in each and every include folder. The task for creating the filters becomes a full day job. On the other hand, I could just drag the whole folder from Explorer onto the project inside VS2010 but it will put all header/source files in there without any filters, rendering it worthless: you can't possible search within 100 files for the right one without having some sort of hierarchy..

Question is:
Is VS2010 having some obscure way of importing a folder AND preserving the folder structure as filters? Looks to me that M$FT people who created VS2010 think that M$FT is the only animal in the jungle and you MUST pollute the sources folder with builders projects so you can leverage "show hiden files" to include them in the project along with the folder structure. That is absurd IMHO...

Comment: Seriously,why do you maintain VS2010 project files if you use CMake ? *(also, please be more neutral and stop writing "M$")*

Comment: You can write a one-liner script which generates there relevant portion of the `.filters` file. Run it under Linux or Cygwin, or write it in `.ps1` or `.bat`.

Comment: @Synxix: You are right. My apologies. I was just venting... I must keep VS2010 around because I do love diversity. The other members of my team responsible for windows maintenance want to use VS2010 because they feel productive in it (or so they thought until now...).

Comment: @Notinlist: I was about to do just that. I thought that I will find the wonder "click your way through it" solution to the problem. Apparently, that is just me dreaming :(. Back to good old shell script...

Comment: I am not against the use of VS2010 (I use it for example), but I think you should stick with only CMake. Using CMake one can generate VS2010 project files (and also makefiles). It is very simple to do, you can even make a small `*.bat` script to call CMake (if the dev is very lazy ;) )

Comment: @Synxis: yes, I know cmake, is my favorite builders as well. I also use it for embedded builds. never tested it to generate sln/vcxproj file tho. I will do that. But if the generated VS2010 project is only compiler-readable (has all files under the same filter), than is worthless for doing coding. The coder is better of using somethig else like NetBeans for example. Is hard to make people switch from their favorite IDE, so I thought that I should make their life easier. Hence, me being stubborn in finding a solution for the filter problem.

Comment: @Notinlist I'm interested in your one liner. Because, realistically, my perl script generating the .filters is 97 lines (including the template) and ... VS is not doing anything with it <foot-in-mouth/>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using CMake, so I advise you stick with only this. You can generate makefiles and VS2010 project files with it (at least). For VS, the generated files are a sln and a bunch of vxproj (one for each project in the CMake script).

In CMake file you can group files, using the command [`source_group`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3asource_group). The filters will be automatically generated for vs according to the source groups. I don't know for other IDE like Code::Blocks or NetBeans.

If you want automatic grouping based on file path *[Comment request]*:

```
# Glob all sources file inside directory ${DIRECTORY}
file(GLOB_RECURSE TMP_FILES
    ${DIRECTORY}/*.h
    ${DIRECTORY}/*.cpp
    ${DIRECTORY}/*.c
)

foreach(f ${TMP_FILES})
    # Get the path of the file relative to ${DIRECTORY},
    # then alter it (not compulsory)
    file(RELATIVE_PATH SRCGR ${DIRECTORY} ${f})
    set(SRCGR "Something/${SRCGR}")

    # Extract the folder, ie remove the filename part
    string(REGEX REPLACE "(.*)(/[^/]*)$" "\\1" SRCGR ${SRCGR})

    # Source_group expects \\ (double antislash), not / (slash)
    string(REPLACE / \\ SRCGR ${SRCGR})
    source_group("${SRCGR}" FILES ${f})
endforeach()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try the source group trick asap and come back with the results

Comment: I accepted the suggestion as a good answer because, theoretically, you can do that and have all those filters. Still, there is a lot of work to be done to group those. Inside cmake for example, I do glob-ing on *.c and *.cpp. For header files, I just add the /include from the relevant project into INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES. Looks to me that grouping is still a daunting manual task even with cmake. Besides, cmake generates working sln, but is very very cluttered and not clean at all. I wish VS would have something like "Add existing items from folders". NetBeans has it, eclipse as well, VS is not...

Comment: And for the sake of completeness, one may wonder why do I keep "make" around when I have cmake. I keep it because cmake is not available on all platforms. On solaris for example, is a real adventure installing cmake. Looks like cmake is not that platform independent after all. That is why stay by my advice: always have the builders completely decoupled from sources.

Comment: Better to have something than nothing. Normally with globing you can automatically make source groups follow the directory structure, for example, after a glob operation you can generate put a file in a source group using foreach. I totally agree with you when you say you want to decouple build from source.

Comment: @Synxis do you have a short example of source groups "following directory structure" by using "foreach" with a "glob operation"? For people new to CMake (like me) finding the simplest things out takes hours.

Comment: @sehe I edited my post, that should answer your question. Feel free to upvote if that helped you ;)

Comment: I will have to see about this. But if this works, I will reconsider using CMake for my project! Looks fine